# woocommerce product attributes empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having problems understanding the following:
I created a custom field in the woocommerce products by the code below.
The custome field shows up and I can fill it as expected.
I don't know how to access the data though.

if I call `$product->get_attributes()` it returns an empty array.
when I echo `$product` though I get an json like return value where all expected values are presented.
But how do I access them?

Thanks in advance

```
function 
 woocom_general_product_data_custom_field() {
  // Create a custom text field

  // Textarea
  woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
     array( 
       'id' => '_textarea', 
       'label' => __( 'textarea' ), 
       'placeholder' => '', 
       'description' => __( '', 
'woocommerce' ) 
     )
 );

}
add_action( 
'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 
'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );



function woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {

  // Save Textarea
  $textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
  if( ! empty( $textarea ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $textarea ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how and where you want to use the value from the custom field, 
for example in order and email confirmations you could use [WooCommerce custom general fields - adding to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024324/woocommerce-custom-general-fields-adding-to-email/62027032#62027032) or for cart & checkout you could use [Display WooCommerce custom product field meta data in Cart and on Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870852/display-woocommerce-custom-product-field-meta-data-in-cart-and-on-checkout/62871514#62871514)

Comment: If you get it with an "echo" you should get the content with var_dump() aswell. Try to paste the result here so that we can see where your values are hiding :)

Comment: I want to use that  input to create some custom HTML code that I  want to use in a UXBlock

Answer (score 1):

got it now.
I found the info in

```
$product->get_meta('_textarea');
```

not in the attributes